# Ошибка в консоли из-за history.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, history-api

У меня есть сайт, серфинг страниц реализован через history.js, в консоли постоянно висит такое сообщение:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Из-за чего это? И насколько это критично?

Comment: У меня подобная была проблема, оказалось, что это все было из-за двух грамматических ошибок в файле-обработчике аджакс-запроса: опечатка в имени переменной (метод mysqli_query($*connection*, $query) ) и в имени метода mysqli_fetch_array() (написал arrray). После исправления все заработало и ошибка пропала!

Comment: Это никак не может быть связано

Answer (score 5):

Вот так делать не надо:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/query", /*async*/ false); // async=false
xhr.send(null);
if (xhr.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Вместо этого следует использовать колбэки:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/query"); // async=true
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Первый способ приводит к задержкам реакции на действия пользователя, в новых браузерах считается устаревшим, поэтому делать так не рекомендуется. Сайт-то работать будет, но UX будет подпорчен.

Comment: У меня такая же ситуация, только никаких обращений подобных выше я не делал. Возможно, что это происходит из-за вредоносного внедрения чужого кода? Потому что других причин не вижу, чтобы исполнялась такая талмуда.

Comment: @IntegralAL это такое же сообщение возникает, когда мы по ajax загружаем html с `<script src="/url"></script>`

Comment: @IntegralAL точнее делаем его append к html

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло то, что предшествующий этому `post` запрос я заменил на `get`, у `get` запросов таких проблем не оказалось.